# Denying access to a directories and files by mod_rewrite rule doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my .htaccess file with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(include/|core/).*\.(php|db)$ - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

It works great but only on my WAMP server... When I use this rules on some web servers I have still access to files in ***include*** and ***core*** directories.

When I remove

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

it works again. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @anubhava, I'm sure.

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule ^(include|core)/ - [F,NC]` rule at the top